# Xcode 5 debugger no objective-c description available

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, xcode5

In Xcode 4, when I use the debugger to print an NSArray count, it would show in the console like this:

```
po [self.array count]
3
```

In Xcode 5, doing this gives me

```
[no Objective-C description available]
```

This seems to be the case with all numerical types. What is the change or reasoning behind this behavior?

Comment: Tried `p` instead of `po`?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The command `po` stands for "Print Object".
self.array.count is type `NSUInteger` which is not an object.
Use the `p` command instead, which is intended to print non object values.
E.g.

```
p self.array.count
```

The [LLDB docs](http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html) are a great resource.

Comment: Interesting, yes that would make sense :D. Didn't know there was a "p" command. Thanks for the response and link.

Comment: Never even knew about 'p'

Comment: The interesting point is that "po" has worked since at least Xcode 3 and through all versions of Xcode 4. But it stopped working in Xcode 5. I agree with @matjan.

Answer (score 2):

In the meantime, I found that if you enclose any numerical type into an NSNumber, it would print out in the console like this:

```
int index = 1;

po index
[no Objective-C description available]
po @(index)
1

po @([self.array count])
3
```

Comment: Nope... error: illegal type 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') used in a boxed expression